# Trying to read multiple lines from txt file separated with :, but I'm getting imbRecoverableException caught from worker -> parseNext

Tags: parent-child, message, definition, ibm-integration-bus

As I'm new to IBM MQ and IIB I'm trying to experiment around with online tutorials. At the moment I'm trying to make a simple app that reads several lines in txt file separated by colon and writes them into XML file. Currently I'm stuck at reading multiple lines from file. I know how to make it work with only one line, but can't with more than one. I do know that there should be a parent-child relationship  between two complex types but can't configure them properly. Also im using RFHUtil to send message file into queue.

Since I can't find much googling it, I hope someone with right knowledge could help around.

Don't have any code, but got my message definition picture: http://prnt.sc/nv9npr

Here is the error I'm getting: http://prnt.sc/nv9nyi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So two things I can see in your current screen shots.

In the first screenshot I can see \r\n i.e. CRLF which indicates that your separator needs to either be CRLF or your model needs to deal with the CRLF.

In the second you've got a partially parsed message. Try setting the Advanced Parser options on your Input node to ParseComplete things will still blow up but you should get some better diagnostic information in the ExceptionList.

Looks like you are trying use the MRM parser which has been replaced by the DFDL parser. I suggest you find some tutorials on the DFDL parser, it's much more efficient. Also there is support built into the Toolkit which will let you debug the Message Model you create [Testing a DFDL schema by parsing test input data](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/df20066_.htm)

Comment: I've used DFDL as you suggested and it worked. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Welcome. Doing a search for "github iib" will turn up some interesting links including this one https://developer.ibm.com/integration/resources/ibm-integration-bus-v10-tutorials-on-github/ which provides some more insights into DFDL along with other things.